# if all method confusion python

Tags: python

I saw the tutorial on Youtube on how to solve Project Euler`s problem 7 and have found this piece of code:

```
    numbers_prime_to_find = 10001
    x = 2
    list_of_primes = []
    while (len(list_of_primes) < numbers_prime_to_find):
        if all(x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes):  # for prime in list_of_primes:

            list_of_primes.append(x)  # if x%prime
        x+=1
    print(list_of_primes[-1])

main()
```

It seems pretty obvious to me except this one line:
`if all(x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes)`

Can someone try to explain this to me as I am struggling badly to find information about this method? Thanks in advance ^-^

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: What exactly is confusing?

Comment: I mean, the first iteration confuses me, how can we .append(x), cause if we divide 2 by none in the list what do we get??

Comment: If `x % prime != 0` is true for all values of `prime`, then `all` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write this:

```
(x + 1 for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

it is called a "generator" and is like a `for` loop. It kind of returns:

```
(2, 3, 4)
```

It actually returns a "generator" object that you can treat like most other iterables but it is easiest to understand first as a normal tuple.

In your case, you are doing:

```
(x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes)
```

so the function being done to every element of the list of primes is `x % prime != 0`.

This is calculating `x % prime` which is "x modulo prime" which is the remainder left over when you divide `x` by `prime`.

For example, `7 % 3` is `1` because 3 goes into 7 2 times, with remainder 1.

Then you see if this remainder equals `0`.

The `all` function accepts an iterable and returns `True` if all elements are `True` and `False` if all elements are `False`.

So the `if` statement only succeeds if no prime number in the list of primes divides into x with 0 remainder.

To say that another way, the `if` statement only succeeds if no prime in the list is a "factor" of x.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "tuple comprehension". `(x+1 for x in [1,2,3])` is a generator expression.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is kinda stupid, but can u explain how we can divide by prime, if we do not define the list_of_primes and it has a zero value when the program is started. Then we start a for loop and this part confuses me

Comment: I mean, the first iteration confuses me, how can we .append(x), cause if we divide 2 by none in the list what do we get??

Comment: Well you have to know that `all([])` will evaluate to `True`. That is, `all` is `True` for an empty iterator. So in the first iteration, it is like doing `all(())`  which is `True`. So `2` gets appended as the first prime.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

`x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes` is called a "generator expression".

A related syntax is a "list comprehension". `[x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes]` would make a new list, the same length as `list_of_primes`. For each element in `list_of_primes`, the corresponding element in the new list would be `x % prime != 0`, where `prime` is the list element.

The list comprehension produces the same result as the following:

```
newList = []
for prime in list_of_primes:
    newList.append(x % prime != 0 )
```

A "generator expression" is almost the same, but produces a one-time iterable that is computed lazily.

So `all(x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes)` is true if, for every element in list_of_primes, `x % prime != 0`.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is kinda stupid, but can u explain how we can divide by prime, if we do not define the list_of_primes and it has a zero value when the program is started. Then we start a for loop and this part confuses me

Comment: I mean, the first iteration confuses me, how can we .append(x), cause if we divide 2 by none in the list what do we get??

Answer (score 0):

The `all()` function in python takes in an iterable object like a dictionary or list and returns true or false

It returns true only if all the values in the iterable object is true

In `all(x % prime!=0 for prime in list_of_primes)`, the all function is finding the remainder for x/prime where prime is an element in the list list_of_primes

If any number divides perfectly by a prime then the `all()` returns `false( x % prime = 0 )` and doesn't add to the list

Comment: I am sorry if the question is kinda stupid, but can u explain how we can divide by prime, if we do not define the list_of_primes and it has a zero value when the program is started. Then we start a for loop and this part confuses me